# Multi-Thread on ArrayList java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I'm developing an application in JavaFX who "scan" Mp3 files to get ID3tag.

Actually my program works, but the application is slow when there is a lot of songs (mp3).

I use a thread who scan every files from an list of mp3files (path).

I'm wondering if it's possible to use more threads to scan every files 4 by 4 rather than 1 by 1 ?

I'm low with multi-threading from java so I ask for your help. Any advice would be great.

Here is my function :

```
private ArrayList checkMp3files(String sDir)
{
    this.currentData = 0;
    this.filesCorrupted.clear();
    ArrayList<DataSong> newLs = new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList with Data from all Songs scanned
    Task taskScan = new Task<ArrayList<DataSong>>() {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<DataSong> call() throws InterruptedException, IOException, UnsupportedTagException 
        {
            String absoluteLoc;
            String location;
            for(String mp3file : Mp3FileData)
            {
                DataSong ds = new DataSong();
                updateMessage("Scanning " + ++currentData + " of " + nbrOfFiles + " Mp3files");
                updateProgress(currentData, nbrOfFiles);
                    try {
                        mp3 = new Mp3File(mp3file);
                    } catch (InvalidDataException ex) {
                        filesCorrupted.add(mp3file);
                    }
                    long durationLong = mp3.getLengthInSeconds();
                    int durationInt = (int) durationLong;
                    ds.setLenghtOfMp3inSec(durationInt);
                    ds.setBitRateOfMp3(mp3.getBitrate());
                    ds.setSampleRate(mp3.getSampleRate());
                    ds.setVbrOrCbr(mp3.isVbr());
                    if(mp3 != null){
                        ds.setAbsoluteLocation(mp3.getFilename());
                        ds.setLocation(removeSDir(mp3.getFilename(), sDir));
                        if(mp3.hasId3v2Tag())
                        {
                            String artist = "";
                            String album = "";
                            String title = "";
                            String track = "";
                            String year = "";
                            String genDesc = "";
                            String composer = "";
                            String publisher = "";
                            String originalArtist = "";
                            String albumArtist = "";
                            String copyright = "";
                            String url = "";                    
                            ID3v2 id3v2Tag = mp3.getId3v2Tag();
                            try{
                                artist = id3v2Tag.getArtist();
                                album = id3v2Tag.getAlbum();
                                title = id3v2Tag.getTitle();
                                track = id3v2Tag.getTrack();
                                year = id3v2Tag.getYear();
                                genDesc = id3v2Tag.getGenreDescription();
                                composer = id3v2Tag.getComposer();
                                publisher = id3v2Tag.getPublisher();
                                originalArtist = id3v2Tag.getOriginalArtist();
                                albumArtist = id3v2Tag.getAlbumArtist();
                                copyright = id3v2Tag.getCopyright();
                                url = id3v2Tag.getUrl();
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex){
                                System.out.println(mp3file);
                                filesCorrupted.add(mp3file);  
                            }
                            if(!(artist == null) && !(artist.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setArtist(artist);
                            }
                            if(!(album == null) && !(album.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setAlbum(album);
                            }
                            if(!(title == null) && !(title.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setTitle(title);
                            }
                            if(!(track == null) && !(track.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setTrackOnAlbum(track);
                            }
                            if(!(year == null) && !(year.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setYearReleased(year);
                            }
                            if(!(genDesc ==  null) && !(genDesc.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setGenre(genDesc);
                            }
                            if(!( composer == null) && !(composer.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setComposer(id3v2Tag.getComposer());
                            }
                            if(!(publisher ==  null) && !(publisher.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setPublisher(publisher);
                            }
                            if(!(originalArtist ==  null) && !(originalArtist.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setOriginArtist(originalArtist);
                            }
                            if(!(albumArtist == null) && !(albumArtist.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setAlbumArtString(albumArtist);
                            }
                            if(!(copyright == null) && !(copyright.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setCopyright(copyright);
                            }
                            if(!(url == null)&& !(url.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                ds.setUrl(url);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    newLs.add(ds);
                }
            }
            return newLs;
        }
    };
    btnScan.disableProperty().bind(taskScan.runningProperty());
    listAdvance.textProperty().bind(taskScan.messageProperty());
    pi.progressProperty().bind(taskScan.progressProperty());
    taskScan.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) 
        {
            if(newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
            {
                System.out.println("Error : " + taskScan.getException());
                listAdvance.textProperty().unbind();
                btnScan.disableProperty().unbind();
            }
            if(newValue == Worker.State.FAILED)
            {
                listAdvance.textProperty().unbind();
                btnScan.disableProperty().unbind();
                System.out.println("Error : " + taskScan.getException());
            }
        }
    });
    Thread toScanFiles = new Thread(taskScan);
    toScanFiles.start();
    return newLs;
}
```

I already thank you for your answers.

Comment: ThreadPool and dispatch 'read' task for each file?

Comment: the problem is I really don't know how to split the arrayList and say to the other Thread what he must scan. (by example: the first thread scan the first half of the list of songs and the other the second).. Any advice on how I can do this ?